# Can I do parallel fields in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of Xs in a MySQL database. Some Xs do not go together, and I want a table that holds all the pairs of Xs and a boolean that says whether they're OK or not.

This part is simple enough:

```
CREATE TABLE good_x (
    X_id_1 int(10) not null ,
    X_id_2 int(10) not null ,
    is_good tinyint(1) 
    ) ;
```

My question is this: Given Xsub1 and Xsub3 go together.

```
SELECT is_good from good_x where X_id_1 = "Xsub1" and X_id_2 = "Xsub3" ;
```

But what if the data comes in Xsub3, Xsub1? I could have two entries in the table:

```
Xsub1,Xsub3,1
Xsub3,Xsub1,1
```

But then, you have to keep track of two things. In my case, this is a controlled vocabulary so I don't expect much change. But if I want to add a third X, Xsub5, you then get six entries to mess with.

```
Xsub1,Xsub3,Xsub5,1
Xsub1,Xsub5,Xsub3,1
Xsub3,Xsub1,Xsub5,1
Xsub3,Xsub5,Xsub1,1
Xsub5,Xsub1,Xsub3,1
Xsub5,Xsub3,Xsub1,1
```

Which is hard to maintain.

Is there a way I can throw in a bunch of Xs, two or more, and associate that with the boolean, so I don't have to have separate tables for doubles, triples, quads, quints, etc. Is this possible in any SQL, and if so, what's the syntax?

Comment: in this case, Xsub*x* is an id, not the data itself. Just to make that part clear.

Comment: Maybe you can sort the id values before looking them up. Then only one row is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store each valid grouping in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE good_x (x_id CHAR, group_id INT);
```

Seed it with groupings like this:

```
INSERT INTO good_x(x_id,group_id) values ('Xsub3',1);
INSERT INTO good_x(x_id,group_id) values ('Xsub1',1);
```

and for 3:

```
INSERT INTO good_x(x_id,group_id) values ('Xsub3',2);
INSERT INTO good_x(x_id,group_id) values ('Xsub1',2);
INSERT INTO good_x(x_id,group_id) values ('Xsub5',2);
```

Now run a SELECT like this:

```
SELECT 1
FROM   good_x
WHERE  x_id IN ([your list of values])
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING count(1) = n;
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this, it reminded me of things I had forgotten MySQL could do, but I'd likely have a third table, x_group, and then key good_x off x_group.id.

I like that.

Comment: Note how your solution allows to store not just pairs but groups of arbitrary size. Maybe `pair_id` could be renamed :)

Comment: I'm thinking there must be a better way that all the self-joins, but not sure offhand.

Comment: Nice. Extra point if you change them to explicit joins using `ON`.

Comment: s/pair_id/group_id/s

Fair enough.

Comment: @BD.: Just access the table once, group by pair_id, where x_id in (list of appropriate ids), having count(\*)= *n*.

Comment: A small implementation issue is grabbing and holding the group_id before inserting the 2+ x_ids into the table, but I can't expect you to do _all_ my homework, can I? B)

Comment: You can probably create a quick and dirty proc that accepts an array of groups as a parameter to do the insert and group_id assignment for you. Please accept my answer if you're going to use it. Good luck!

Comment: @VarLogRant, consider creating a GUID on the application server, though you could use a separate table that has an autoincrement integer, insert a record, and use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use the IN clause.

```
SELECT is_good 
  from good_x 
 where X_id_1 in ("Xsub1","Xsub3","Xsub5")
   and X_id_2 in ("Xsub1","Xsub3","Xsub5") 
   and X_id_3 in ("Xsub1","Xsub3","Xsub5") ;
```

And if you don't want the same values in diferent columns, you could add

```
   and ( X_id_1 <> X_id_2
   and   X_id_1 <> X_id_3
   and   X_id_2 <> X_id_3 )
```

This, of course, would not be ideal when you have too many columns or different values.

Comment: I'm hoping to make the same basic queries work with up to five x_ids, so I think BD's way is best. But this is useful SQL that my haphazard learning had skipped over. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you order your Xs somehow (e.g. by their numerical artificial PK), you will only need to store one set of Xs, not all permutations. The cost of it would be the necessity to order Xs before query.

OTOH the query listing 'what is X compatible with' will become more expensive (you'll need 2 indexes and 2 queries).

You can use a totally general solution, like this:

```
create table compatible (
  group_id number not null,
  x_id number foreign key references x(id),
  primary key (group_id, x_id)
);
create unique index ... on compatible(x_id, group_id)
```

To store the fact that any number of Xs are compatible, you create as many records in `compatible` table with the same arbitrary `group_id`. You can efficiently find whether some items are compatible, querying their `group_id`s and checking if they match (use `exists`). You can efficiently find all things that are compatible with particular X. You're not constrained by the size of the group of compatible items, and never care about permutations.

Comment: I see that. It's just that complexity pushed off the SQL table (which I created) is pushed on the client software (which I wrote), and I'm hoping that, in this case, Fred Brooks is wrong and there *is* a silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution depends a bit on the nature of the is_good relationship and the X values.

If the X values can be ordered, then you can use ordering to store a pairwise relationship with just one record rather than two.  Just store `min(x1, x2)` in `x_id_1`, and `max(x1, x2)` in `x_id_2` whenever you insert.  Then use the same approach when querying over the pairs: `select ... where x_id_1 = min(x_sub_1, x_sub_2) and x_id_2 = max(x_sub_1, x_sub_2)`.

If the `is_good` relation is symmetric and transitive, and if there is a fairly small and stable set of X values, then an alternative approach might be to use bitwise logic.  Each bit represents a distinct X value, and each record in the table contains a bit pattern that denotes that all X bits with a "1" value are in an `is_good` relationship with each other.  Querying would simply involve finding the record with the proper bits set: `select ... where x_bitfield & my_query_bitfield = my_query_bitfield`.

Comment: in this case, Xs are id codes, which I usually set as int(10).

I think I'll go BD's way (will accept once I have code working), in part because it more elegantly handles triples, but it never occurred to me to use min() and max() in the INSERT and WHERE parts of a query. Very hackish, in the best way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, using your current design, is just ensure that when you store them in the pairs in the database, you store them in order.

For example, for pairs 'Xsub1' and 'Xsub3', store them in order alphabetically. Then when searching for them, you must order them alphabetically in the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
good_x
WHERE x_id_1 = 'Xsub1'
AND x_id_2 = 'Xsub3'
```

This will avoid duplicates and only require a minimum amount of preprocessing.

I think that BD's solution is better, if you don't mind a redesign.

Comment: "But what if the data comes in Xsub3, Xsub1?" I guess we need to know more about this process.

Comment: @BD, your solution is better. I edited my answer, but any application can reorder parameters. :)

Comment: I do that elsewhere. Reasonable code for pairs, but it doesn't scale.